# Where are OpenOffice writer custom styles saved?

Tags: styles, openoffice-writer

I am creating new header styles in OpenOffice (for example `My Header 1`, etc...), but where are these custom styles saved? Is it in the document or the application? If I open my document on another pc, will these styles still apply?

Answer (score 1):

After performing a couple of tests, it seems like custom styles are saved in documents. If you want to create a document with custom styles, you need to make a copy of an existing one.

Comment: Or rather create a new template based on the document and use it for future docs.